# value map setting" of a shapefile will be lost when you upload to a POSTGIS database?

Tags: postgis, qgis-2.18

I am busy making a skeleton shapefile, with many value maps either preset (in the shapefile itself) or either created by a link to a table.

I have also set up a POSTGIS Database where the shapefile and those extra tables will be stored.

Whoever I am concerend that when I am gonna upload this shapefile it will both lose the value "preset" value maps and the  value map relation link to my tables.

The reason I believe this is that when I had saved my skeleton shapefile as a different file to test something. I lost the value map settings.

Will this also happen when I upload the shapefile's to my POSTGIS database? If so I can warn them about they need to reset it manually everytime in Offline projects.

Answer (score 1):

It will loose its value map relations if they are part of the same dataset or part of another table. The problem is when you import the file into postgis it becomes a new layer. And all the layer options are stored within the QGIS project for each specific layer.

If the values are from the same dataset you may just copy layer definitions (right click the layer -> Style -> Copy Style and then Paste it to the new layer from PostGIS).

When the value map uses a foreign table you have the problem that the imported table is a new one with a new adress. Therfore you have to manually recreate the  relation.

Comment: By same dataset you mean the same shapefile, so an interal value map?

Comment: I did understand it this way that you have them within the shapefile as an attributefield. Seems like i did interpret that wrong.

Comment: I originally planed to make the value maps linked to tables, so that they can be updated if necessary. But considering I want to make everything of  shapefile in as less files as possible. Now I am making them internal by loading the vallues from another layer. But not actually making them linked to it.